# A line not intersecting points in the plane

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, geometry

Is it possible to draw a finite or infinite set S of points in the plane, such that any line drawn in this plane neither intersects with  exactly one point in S or an infinite number of points in S?

Comment: S being the empty set satisfies this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe the set of points (x,y) such that $x y = ±1$ satisfies the conditions.

The set consists of 4 segments of hyperbolas.  Any straight line crosses at least 2 of these segments resulting in 2 to 4 intersections.  Except for the lines x=0 or y=0 which cross none.

Here's a graph:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Ankit for adding the graph.

Answer (score 9):

It is not possible with any finite or countably infinite set.

Take any point *P* in the set.  For each other point *Q* in the set, draw a line between *P* and *Q*.  Then take the angle between line *PQ* and the horizontal axis.  This forms a set of angles *A*.

If *S* is countable, then the set of angles *A* must also be countable (since there is at most once angle per point in *S*).  However, since angles are real numbers, and the real numbers are uncountable, by [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) we can construct some angle *x* not in our (countable) set *A*.

If we take the line going through the point *P* at the angle *x*, then this new line will not pass through any other point in the set; if it did, then its angle would have been in set *A*.  Therefore, we have constructed a line that intersects exactly one point of the set *S*.

Since this is not allowed, and the only assumption we made about *S* was that it was countable, it must be the case that *S* is infinite and uncountable.

Comment: When you say "since there is at most once angle per point in S", don't you mean "at most one angle per pair of points in S"? And *that's* justified because the Cartesian product of a countable number of countable sets is countable.

Comment: @LieutenantZipp No, we are only considering lines that pass through the fixed point P, so each point in S other than P defines a line. If S is finite then there are |S|-1 lines. However I think your variation also results in a working proof.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Apologies for the misreading. I thought you were taking all lines through all pairs of points, which now seems to me just an unnecessarily thorough variant of what you actually did.

Answer (score 5):

To rule out @hexomino's trivial solution (empty set) let us require that every straight line intersects S in fintitely many and at least 2 points.

Then one simple way to construct S is

> using two shifted disjoint copies of the graph of the function
>  *y*=*x*<sup>3</sup>, for example *y*<sub>±</sub>(*x*) = *x*<sup>3</sup>±1.
>  Any straight line is either vertical and will intersect both graphs at the same
>  *x*-offset or of the form *y*<sub>L</sub>(*x*) = *ax*+*b*. As each of *y*<sub>L</sub>(*x*)=*y*<sub>+</sub>(*x*) and *y*<sub>L</sub>(*x*)=*y*<sub>-</sub>(*x*) has between 1 and 3 solutions we get between 2 and 6 intersections.

Comment: I’m not sure how this rules out S as the empty set. The empty set is a set containing zero points. Any line drawn in the plane intersects with exactly zero points in S (not exactly one, and not infinite) since there are zero points in the set. Your answer constructs a distinctly non-empty set S, which doesn’t do anything to disprove that the empty set doesn’t work.

Comment: My argument is as follows: OP as it stands allows for the empty set as a valid solution. As this is probably not what OP intended I changed the question to explicitly rule out empty intersections.

Comment: Oh, you’ve changed _the question_, and provided an answer to the changed question. Fair enough.